# YAPdatabase connexion is null

Tags: ios, objective-c, yapdatabase

I try to install yapdatabase on my project and i have the problem that self.connexion is null.

```
@implementation DataManager

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.database = [[YapDatabase alloc] initWithPath:@"myDtabase.sqlite"];
        self.connexion = [self.database newConnection];  
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSMutableArray *)getArtists {
    NSLog(@"%@", self.connexion);
}
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly construct the path to the database file:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myDtabase.sqlite" ofType:nil]
```

This is a required step to access the resources bundled within your app on iOS.

Comment: Hello, i have add [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource in appdelegate and when i'm log   

NSLog(@"%@", self.connexion); 

The answer is (null)

Comment: Are your sure the file named "myDtabase.sqlite" is included in your app as a resource?